# Long id not being converted correctly

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am making a discord bot with a function that can either accept an id or a mentioned user. However, when I try to take input from the id, I have to convert it to a user but it is converted incorrectly and the user is invalid since getting values from the user object would give me an error: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Command Usage:

```
[Command("Add")]
[Summary("Adds a user")]
public async Task BlacklistUser(Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuildUser user)
{
    User_Flow_control userFlow = new User_Flow_control(Context.Client);

    if (await userFlow.AddUser(user.Id, "New User"))
        await ReplyAsync($"Successfully added <@!{user.Id}> as New User");
    else
    {
        await userFlow.UpdateUser(user.Id, "New User");
        await ReplyAsync($"Successfully updated <@!{user.Id}> as New USer");
    }
}
[Command("Add")]
[Summary("Adds a user")]
public async Task BlacklistUser(ulong userId)
{
     User_Flow_control userFlow = new User_Flow_control(Context.Client);

     SocketUser user = Context.Client.GetUser(userId);

    if (await userFlow.AddUser(user.Id, "New User"))
        await ReplyAsync($"Successfully added <@!{userId}> as New User");
    else
    {
        await userFlow.UpdateUser(user.Id, "New User");
        await ReplyAsync($"Successfully updated <@!{userId}> as New User");
    }
}
```

The Functions:

```
public async Task<bool> AddUser(ulong userId, string status = "New User")
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Adding user {_client.GetUser(userId).ToString() /* It would fail here */} ({userId}) to the database.");

    // Ensure that a user profile has not already been created.
    List<DataRow> serverUsers = new List<DataRow>();

    // Start REading database.

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MemberServerStatus", connectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        //get the infraction data
        DataTable serverUsersTable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(serverUsersTable);

        serverUsers.Capacity = serverUsersTable.Rows.Count; //resize it to minimum size

        foreach (DataRow row in serverUsersTable.Rows)
        {
            serverUsers.Add(row);
        }
    }

    // Do the check
    foreach (DataRow row in serverUsers)
    {
        if (Convert.ToUInt64(row[1]) == userId)
            return false;
    }

    // Verified not a duplicate

    // Add the new user

    string query = "INSERT INTO MemberServerStatus VALUES (@Username, @UserId, @Status)";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        //convert user id
        long longId = Convert.ToInt64(userId);

        //set the values
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", _client.GetUser(userId).ToString()); // Fail here.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", longId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", status);

        //Execute and add the user into the db
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    return true;
}
```

```
public async Task UpdateUser(ulong userId, string status)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Updating user {_client.GetUser(userId).ToString() /* It would fail here */} ({userId}) from the database.");

    string query = "UPDATE MemberServerStatus SET Username = @Username, Status = @Status WHERE UserID = @UserId";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        //convert user id
        long longId = Convert.ToInt64(userId);

        //set the values
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", _client.GetUser(userId).Username); // Fail here.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", longId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", status);

        //Execute and add the user into the db
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value user is entering? What is the value you are getting after conversion? Which is the code that converts the user input value to long? Which line in the code gives you NullReferenceException?

Comment: `_client.GetUser(userId).Username` - either the `_client` is null or the `GetUser` method is returning null, which would mean either the id is wrong or the user is not in cache.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The user should either mention a user or input the id of the user. In this case, the way it accepts the ulong id is broken for some reason. Also, the input should have already been directly accepted as a ulong since that's how the Discord API should work.

Comment: @Anu6is I think the `GetUser` method id returning null and the id I am entering is correct.

Comment: So the user isn't in cache. The SocketGuildUser parameter parses ulong on it's own btw. If you are sure the id is correct, you can enable the AlwaysDownloadUsers option in the client config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my functions work, however, the user needs to be in the same server for the id -> user conversion. Therefore, I will have to change my code to accommodate that. If someone does somehow know how to get a user from an id where the bot has no mutual servers with the target user, please let me know.

Edit:
Thanks to @Anu6is for telling me about the rest client. Now I can get the user even when there are no mutual servers.

My new code to get the user with no mutual servers will use:

```
_client.Rest.GetUserAsync(userId).Result
```

instead of:

```
_client.GetUser(userId)
```

Comment: You can make a rest request using, the Rest property exposed on the client.

Comment: Thanks @Anu6is for helping me out! Now my code works!